# What's "worn size 'large' gloves" referring to in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Well now I know I've done at least two things Trump hasn't... **worn size 'large' gloves** and been in a grocery store.

This is a tweet comment quoted by [this article](https://www.yahoo.com/news/president-trump-said-apos-id-010316447.html). As I understand, he is saying that there are two things Trump hasn't done yet, number 1 is "**worn size 'large' gloves**", and number 2 is "**been in a grocery store**". But I don't understand why the guy put **worn size 'large' gloves**? Any underlying meaning for it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The author is simply continuing a joke about Trump. Trump is often ridiculed for having small hands.

> Marco Rubio told supporters last week that GOP presidential rival Donald Trump is "always calling me 'little Marco.'"
>
> "He is taller than me, he's like 6' 2", which is why I don't understand why his hands are the size of someone who is 5' 2"," Rubio joked. "Have you seen his hands? And you know what they say about men with small hands -- "

Source: [The History Behind the Donald Trump 'Small Hands' Insult](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/history-donald-trump-small-hands-insult/story?id=37395515)

Answer (score 8):

Em.♦ has clarified the allusion in that answer, but just to be clear about the syntax:

> I've done at least two things Trump hasn't ... [I've] worn size "large" gloves and [I've] been in a grocery store.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good example of why, in English, we use hyphens for "phrasal adjectives."

I suspect that the quotes around the word "large" got in the way , but had this been written "worn size-'large' gloves" it may have been more clear.

"Size 'large'" is different than "large size" in that the former refers to clothing manufacturing sizes and the latter refers to big things.

Answer (score 2):

Following from Em.♦'s answer:

Trump, referring to Rubio's comments, referenced a size 'large' glove in a humourous way:

> I mean people were writing, “How are Mr. Trump’s hands?” My hands are fine. You know, my hands are normal. Slightly large, actually. In fact, I buy a **slightly smaller than large glove**, okay?

Source: [A transcript of Donald Trump’s meeting with The Washington Post editorial board](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/post-partisan/wp/2016/03/21/a-transcript-of-donald-trumps-meeting-with-the-washington-post-editorial-board/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.b11642a77408)

The joke here is that the tweet author has worn a size large glove, but Trump hasn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is the larger [quote regarding Trump's hands](https://www.businessinsider.com/marco-rubio-donald-trump-small-hands-2016-2), for context -

> "The other thing he says — he's always calling me 'Little Marco,'"
>   Rubio said. "And I'll admit ... he's taller than me, he's like 6-2.
>   Which is why I don't understand why his hands are the size of someone
>   who's 5-2."
>
> The crowd laughed and cheered.
>
> "And you know what they say about men with small hands," Rubio
>   continued, pausing for effect and grinning as the crowd reacted.

For what it's worth, Rubio's implication is a joke, [proven false](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/hand-size-trump-debate/).

Comment: I'm glad you set things straight there. All along, I was thinking that Marco meant something else entirely. "If you're a kid, your heart is about the same size as your fist, and if you're an adult, it's about the same size as two fists."
www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/heart/heartfacts.html

Comment: But if you are short in stature, very slim, have small hands and feet and a small nose...It's going to be very unlikely. BTW is that your answer to the question or is it really meant to be a comment on Em.♦'s answer?